# Fill custom shape in Draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I have a custom round icon/stencil/shape were the connection points work fine, but when I "**fill**" it, the fill border is a rectangle.
Can I modify the fill border in some easy way or is there a setting for this?
Example:
[image: Aruba custom Icon]

I hope it shows the issue well. Notice the black connection that snaps correctly to the round shape.